# Connected cars: Skills needed for a security specialist

Tags: attacks, professional-education

Connected cars are being mass produced by many car manufactures such as Audi, GM, Honda and Hyundai (Founding members of the [Open Automotive Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Automotive_Alliance)).

Recently I have read a scaring [article](http://www.wired.com/2015/07/hackers-remotely-kill-jeep-highway/) about what crackers could do by hacking such a connected car.

What are the most important technical skills or knowledge areas a connected car security specialist must have in order successfully protect cars/companies/people against such threats?

Comment: I guess @Milen did a very good job naming some key areas such CAN-bus, IMHO and LIN bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically:

- Solid understanding of CAN-bus (most important IMHO), and maybe LIN
  bus - error handling, isolation techniques, message structure, HLPs.
- Working knowledge of ECU, sensor electronics and control modules
- Advanced reverse engineering skills (sniffing, protocol analysis, cryptography)

Answer (score 3):

Virtually all new connected cars have IT security issues. First of all, when we talk about *connected* cars, we refer to wireless connection. So having a good knowledge of how [802.1 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3580) list  and  technologies such as LAN function is a must.

Also there is a wide range of software that connected cars may use, including operating systems such as Microsoft Windows and all sorts of software that  [covers both proprietary and open source software](http://www.wired.com/2012/12/automotive-os-war/all/) which thing involves million lines of code leading to eventual vulnerabilities such as [this  exploit of  Progressive’s Snapshot driver tracking tool](https://threatpost.com/holes-in-progressive-dongle-could-lead-to-car-hacks/110511) in order to hack into the onboard networks of certain automobiles.  The hacking possibilities go even further to [take control of the brakes of the car](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2013/07/24/hackers-reveal-nasty-new-car-attacks-with-me-behind-the-wheel-video/). So you can guess that a good knowledge of embedded softaware even from the programming point of view is a must.

**Conclusion:**

Having a good knowledge of WiFi technologies and the embedded software as well as programming are surely required skills. Last but not the least, you need a basic understanding of a car's electronic and mechanical engineering.

[image]

[Source of the image](http://click-accenture.com/connected-cars-growing-importance-in-car-technologies/#.VbiMapOli1E).

Comment: Fundamentally, the only reason for this is unchecked bounds and character sets on the inputs. It's even worse if for some reason, there's a full fledged web server put into the car just for receiving and communicating with a remote host. That is, assuming remote host compromise. Of course if physically it has been taken over, then there's no real guarantee of anything.